# How to open infowindows with javascript Google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

The code below shows what I am trying to do. I am trying to open each infowindow by clicking on the li element created in createList(). This is not working..it display that 'marker' is not defined, which I understand, but I do not know how to correct this. You can view the source code and the live map here: http://home.messiah.edu/~dw1248/dev/lodgingTest.html

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .list {
        width: 25%;
        height: 75%;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%; 
        left: 1.5%;
        background-color: white; 
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
        font-size: 0.82em;
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
        padding-top: 48px;
        overflow: scroll;
      }
      li {
        list-style-type: none;
      }
      .listHeader {
        width: 25%;
        height: 40px;
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
        z-index: 3;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%; 
        left: 1.5%;
        background-color: white; 
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);  
      }
      .listHeader h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1em;  
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      var service;
      var infowindow;

      function initMap() {
          var messiah = {
              lat: 40.158350,
              lng: -76.987454
          };
          var center = {
              lat: 40.158350,
              lng: -77.076
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: center,
              zoom: 11
          });

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: messiah,
              map: map,
              title: 'Messiah College'
          });

          var request = {
              location: messiah,
              radius: 10000,
              type: ['lodging']
          }

          service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
          service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


      }

      function callback(results, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            results.forEach(createMarker);
            results.forEach(createList);
          }
      }


      function createMarker(place) {
          var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: {
                  url: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/circle.png',
                  anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
                  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 17)
              },
              position: place.geometry.location
          });

          ///////////Look Here To Start Next Time

          marker.addListener('click', function() {

            var request = {
                reference: place.reference
            };

            service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
            var content = '<div><strong>' + details.name + '</strong><br>' + details.formatted_address + '<br>' + details.formatted_phone_number;
            if (!!details.website) {content += '<br><a href=' + details.website + ' target= "_blank"> Website </a>'}
            if (!!details.rating) {content += '<br>' + 'Rating: ' + details.rating }
              infowindow.setContent(content);

              infowindow.open(map, marker);

            });

          });
      }

          function createList(place) {

    var request = {
        reference : place.reference,
    };

    service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

            $('.list').append('<li class="listItem">' + details.name + '</li><br/>');
            $('.listItem').click(function() {

            var content = '<div><strong>' + details.name + '</strong><br>' + details.formatted_address + '<br>' + details.formatted_phone_number;
            if (!!details.website) {content += '<br><a href=' + details.website + ' target= "_blank"> Website </a>'}
            if (!!details.rating) {content += '<br>' + 'Rating: ' + details.rating }
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

        } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                createList(place);
            }, 200);
        }
    });
}



      window.onload = initMap;

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map">

    </div>
    <div class="listHeader">
        <h1>Lodging List</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="list">

    <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to declare `var marker;` outside the function `createMarker()` then it will definitely work for ... i've tried

Comment: When I do that, then the infowindow only opens at one location and it is not the correct info for that place.

Comment: this is because the content of infowindow is override every time, when the new marker is created, so that's why it is showing last record details. The solution is to use unique id of infowindow for each marker detail...

Comment: Being that all of the infowindows are created with one block of code, how can I assign a unique id to each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, in case you want to interact with markers, you should keep their reference somewhere. That's why _markers below. Also you are assigning the click event wrong. Your are assigning events multiple times. Hope this helps, check the code below.

or in working here : 
http://codepen.io/ravish_hacker/pen/pyeMbL

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .list {
            width: 25%;
            height: 75%;
            z-index: 2;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10%;
            left: 1.5%;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 2px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
            font-size: 0.82em;
            padding-left: 8px;
            padding-right: 8px;
            padding-top: 48px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
        li {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .listHeader {
            width: 25%;
            height: 40px;
            padding-left: 8px;
            padding-right: 8px;
            z-index: 3;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10%;
            left: 1.5%;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 3px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
        }
        .listHeader h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script>
        var _markers = [];
        var map;
        var service;
        var infowindow;

        function initMap() {
            var messiah = {
                lat: 40.158350,
                lng: -76.987454
            };
            var center = {
                lat: 40.158350,
                lng: -77.076
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: center,
                zoom: 11
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: messiah,
                map: map,
                title: 'Messiah College'
            });

            var request = {
                location: messiah,
                radius: 10000,
                type: ['lodging']
            }

            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


        }

        function callback(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                    createList(results[i], i);
                }
                //results.forEach(createMarker);
                //results.forEach(createList);
            }
        }


        function createMarker(place) {
            var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: {
                    url: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/circle.png',
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 17)
                },
                position: place.geometry.location
            });
            _markers.push(marker);
            ///////////Look Here To Start Next Time

            marker.addListener('click', function() {

                var request = {
                    reference: place.reference
                };

                service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
                    var content = '<div><strong>' + details.name + '</strong><br>' + details.formatted_address + '<br>' + details.formatted_phone_number;
                    if (!!details.website) {
                        content += '<br><a href=' + details.website + ' target= "_blank"> Website </a>'
                    }
                    if (!!details.rating) {
                        content += '<br>' + 'Rating: ' + details.rating
                    }
                    infowindow.setContent(content);

                    infowindow.open(map, marker);

                });

            });
        }

        function createList(place, index) {

            var request = {
                reference: place.reference,
            };

            service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

                    $('.list').append('<li class="listItem" id = "' + details.place_id + '"">' + details.name + '</li><br/>');
                    $('#' + details.place_id).click(function() {

                        var content = '<div><strong>' + details.name + '</strong><br>' + details.formatted_address + '<br>' + details.formatted_phone_number;
                        if (!!details.website) {
                            content += '<br><a href=' + details.website + ' target= "_blank"> Website </a>'
                        }
                        if (!!details.rating) {
                            content += '<br>' + 'Rating: ' + details.rating
                        }
                        infowindow.setContent(content);
                        console.log(index);
                        infowindow.open(map, _markers[index]);
                    });

                } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        createList(place);
                    }, 200);
                }
            });
        }



        window.onload = initMap;
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map">
    </div>
    <div class="listHeader">
        <h1>Lodging List</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
        <div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great solution! I knew this could be done, I was just stuck. Thank you so much for your help.